# ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT Nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean

I was using Laravel Forge and stopped using it due to a problem with my card. So I continued on my own with Digital Ocean.

I followed the below instructable to apply SSL to the site.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04-es

This procedure indicated some errors que posteriormente solucioné:
**For example:**

```
maquino@codigobyte:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "todocontenidoweb.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.todocontenidoweb.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "todocontenidoweb.com" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.todocontenidoweb.com" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

The issue is that my site is down, I'm already on the third day and Digital Ocean support tells me that they don't see a problem in the configurations. But the site is down.
On the next page it shows me a problem with the secure connection.

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=todocontenidoweb.com

At this moment there are several things that make me believe that I have a problem in the following configuration:
In /etc/nginx/sites-enabled$
I have 3 files and one of them is my site todocontenidoweb.com
In todocontenidoweb.com:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name todocontenidoweb;
server_tokens off;
root /home/forge/todocontenidoweb.com/public;
```

In the server_name line all web content; I understand that I should put todocontenidoweb.com www.todocontenidos web.com
But it doesn't allow me and it gives me an error in the certificate if I do this.
I would really appreciate it if someone could help me to solve this situation.

**EDITION**

> File: /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomain.com

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
#include forge-conf/todocontenidoweb.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name todocontenidoweb.com www.todocontenidoweb.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root /home/forge/todocontenidoweb.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    # ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    # ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY13>
    # ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    # ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    #include forge-conf/todocontenidoweb.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/todocontenidoweb.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name todocontenidoweb.com www.todocontenidoweb.com;

    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
#include forge-conf/todocontenidoweb.com/after/*;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Edit

As you can see below, the site is returning a 301 respose and redirecting to https site, but none of your nginx configs are running on port 443
[image]

//End of Edit

There seems to an issue with your nginx config. It seems like your config is only allowing port 80 and not 443. Browsers expect to get 443 as port (unless you otherwise specify) as ssl port. And it seems like you're using some redirect to redirect users from http to https, only problem is you're not running any https service on port 443.

I could be an issue with your nginx config. make sure that the `server` entry that has the ssl input, also running on port 443.

If you did install ssl with let's encrypt, you can try to [generate certificate manually](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#manual) and then you can modify nginx [config to run on port 443 as ssl](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)

You can follow [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-on-centos-7) from digitalocean , just replace the certificates path with lets-encrypt one

Edit 2 :

I don't think this part should be commented out

```
    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    # ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    # ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY13>
    # ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    # ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;
```

As you're essentially not serving any ssl certificate through the 443 port.

Here is an example server from [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-on-centos-7). As you can see, they're serving a private and public key. Once you generate your certificate, you need to enter the path of those.

```
server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;

    server_name your_server_ip;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
}
```

End of Edit

Comment: Hello dear Ronodip Basak, first of all thank you very much from the bottom of my heart for your help. I did the indicated steps and I keep getting the same message on the website. Could it be that it takes time to apply the changes?

Comment: Hi, how are you, I'll add if you can see how the edited file looks. Maybe there you can detect a problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should check the new edit I just added

Comment: Would have been hard explaining that in a comment

Comment: Thank you so much! remove NGINX from root next to CERTBOT and followed the steps from scratch and it works fine.